# Getting clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: go, clang

I am trying to build my code. And when i try to do: `go build` i get the below error:

```
/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
duplicate symbol _FetchPEMRootsCTX509_MountainLion in:
    /var/folders/v8/94mqr56n2yqd9pcj8rd21cyr0000gp/T/go-link-418396971/000033.o
    /var/folders/v8/94mqr56n2yqd9pcj8rd21cyr0000gp/T/go-link-418396971/000036.o
duplicate symbol _FetchPEMRootsCTX509 in:
    /var/folders/v8/94mqr56n2yqd9pcj8rd21cyr0000gp/T/go-link-418396971/000033.o
    /var/folders/v8/94mqr56n2yqd9pcj8rd21cyr0000gp/T/go-link-418396971/000036.o
duplicate symbol _useOldCodeCTX509 in:
    /var/folders/v8/94mqr56n2yqd9pcj8rd21cyr0000gp/T/go-link-418396971/000033.o
    /var/folders/v8/94mqr56n2yqd9pcj8rd21cyr0000gp/T/go-link-418396971/000036.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Tried searching for this issue, but couldn't find any thing conclusive. Can someone help me with:

1. What this error is all about? Since my program runs fine as in `go run` works perfectly.
2. How do I debug it? As in, Is there any more flags which I can use that will give me extra logs? I tried `go build -v` and output was same.

Comment: stuck with the same error. Did you find any solution to this.

Comment: Try `CGO_ENABLED=0 go build`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons why this error is coming because you're running the function of the same package along with the package name. Example:

```
package server

...

server.functionOfSamePackage()
```

So update it to:

```
package server

...

functionOfSamePackage()
```

Comment: Do read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help as your answer wasn't in good shape (formatting issue, etc.) previously (before editing). That'll make you write good, formatted answers from next time onwards.